Python eval: SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
I want to evaluate a string of a file path to open the file, but I get the error:
File :1
'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop_Revenue\Input'  + str(yr) + '\' + 'Survey' + YY + '_revenue.xlsx'
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
The syntax error is at '\'
I want to use eval as my file path is passed into a function later

url= " 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\_Revenue\\Input\\'  + str(yr) + '\\' + 'Survey' + YY + '_revenue.xlsx'"

def test (yr):
   yr=yr
   YY=str(yr)[2:]

   survey_url= eval(url)

test(2015)


Why are you calling eval on a filepath string?  Just build a normal string. What is the full traceback of the error message?  Because I get SyntaxError: ... truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape on the eval.

url = rf'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\_Revenue\Input\{yr}\Survey{YY}_revenue.xlsx'

Among other things, that space at the beginning of url is likely to cause problems.

@Mark Tolonen: I have provided more details in my question. Thanks

Don't use eval.  Remove the double-quotes from the url and you won't need it, or use my suggestion instead.

@KeithThompson Why?

@nocomment Apparently url is intended to be a Windows file path, starting with "C:\".  Adding a space at the beginning makes it a different path, and very likely an invalid one. (It depends on what you do with it; some things might ignore leading whitespace.)

@KeithThompson That space is  before the ', i.e., outside the string. And eval ignores it. And I don't see what you'd do that doesn't.

@nocomment You're right, I did miss something. The string url does start with a space, but passing it to eval treats it as a Python expression, and the leading space is ignored in that context. If a string is going to be treated as a URL,, it shouldn't have a leading space, but url is treated as a representation of a Perl expression, not directly as a URL. (eval() is not the right tool for this.)

eval is nearly always the wrong answer.  If you want to re-use a format string, use .format() to pass variables to an unprocessed format string:
# raw string to skip escaping backslashes.
# unprocessed format string (use .format later)
URL = r'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\_Revenue\Input\{yr}\Survey{YY}_revenue.xlsx'

def test(yr):
    YY = yr % 100
    # ** passes a dictionary argument as named parameters.
    # locals() is a dictionary of the local variables, e.g.
    # {'yr': 2024, 'YY': 24}.
    return URL.format(**locals())

print(test(2015))
print(test(2024))

Output:
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\_Revenue\Input\2015\Survey15_revenue.xlsx
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\_Revenue\Input\2024\Survey24_revenue.xlsx

Another version without the **locals() trickery:
URL = r'C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\_Revenue\Input\{0}\Survey{1}_revenue.xlsx'

def test(yr):
    YY = yr % 100
    return URL.format(yr, YY)  # {0} is first parameter to format, {1} the 2nd, etc.

print(test(2015))
print(test(2024))


Use f-strings for a more intuitive way to pass variables in strings, and r-strings to handle \\
url= rf"C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\_Revenue\\Input\\{yr}\\Survey{YY}_revenue.xlsx"

Wanted to edit your answer above, but you're missing the f in your f-string. (Edits need at least 6 characters of change)
